# Is it possible to use custom controls?

Tags: ios

I'd like to use a custom check box control in iOS App.

My custom check box will use the UIButton and shows a toggle image between checked and unchecked image when user touch it.

I wonder if Apple's HIG allows this custom control.

Is it possible?

Sorry for can't upload the checkbox image because I'm in company of preventing upload here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

may it will help you,

.h file

```
IBOutlet UIButton *btnremember;

BOOL rememberflag;
```

.m file

```
-(IBAction)Button_clicked:(id)sender
{
  if (rememberflag)
  {
        [btnremember setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Uncheckbox-bg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];// give name of your image
        rememberflag=NO;
  }
  else
  {
      [btnremember setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox-bg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];// give name of your image
        rememberflag=YES;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dhaval for help.

Answer (score 0):

yes,
 You can customize buttons as checkbox.
Add images for button and done the logic.